# How to solve Admob importing in Unity problem

Tags: unity-game-engine, import, admob

I just started a new 2D Mobile project and tried to import `admob`

This is the full text that it writes

**Assembly**

```
'Assets/ExternalDependencyManager/Editor/1.2.175/Google.IOSResolver.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Unable to resolve reference 'UnityEditor.iOS.Extensions.Xcode'.
```

Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.

(I use unity on windows)

Comment: This can be easily removed by adding iOS build support. If you are not building for iOS then simply you can ignore this error.

Answer (score 0):

switch the project to IOS or Android and see if it goes away

Answer (score 0):

for me the solution was to install iOS build support via Unity Hub.